# Really messed up my Linux Ubuntu system python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04

Example: I was trying to update my system today and I got this error:

```
wli@ubuntu:~$ update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ._gi import _gobject
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi._gi'
```

Not sure what to do? Ive tried every common fix found in forums online, reinstalling and uninstalling python, everything. The only thing I can think of that may have caused this is that I tried to change my system's python version through a series of convoluted commands in order to force Atom to use python3. Any ideas for how I can fix this? I'd really like to be able to install things on my laptop; I can't even reinstall Ubuntu because that requires actually being able to use Python.

I even made my system point to 2.7.6 using update-alternatives but it still doesn't work.

For reference, the system Python version is now 2.7.6 and I run 14.04.

Comment: Can you put Ubuntu on a flash/USB/thumb drive and reinstall like that?

Comment: Its a stupid observation, but should you have used sudo on that command ??